# Unresolved Reference From Sub Module Test

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, junit4, android-testing

i want use some code in my main module those code presents in the sub module `library` in `androidTest` folder but when compilin the error shown unresolved reference 
here is my code

```
fun performClick(@IdRes idRes: Int)
    = Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(idRes)).perform(ViewActions.click())
```

this in `library` modules `androidTest` folder and it is a common function which is defined in `ViewUtils` kotlin file but when i used this fun from my app module `androidTest` folder it show that unresolved reference but i can implement the code